# Wamp throws a 404 error anywhere but in root

Tags: php, apache, wamp, fat-free-framework

Right.

So, I've got wamp installed and running. The icon is green, `http://localhost/` is working. In wamp, I have fat-free framework at `localhost/fatfree-master`, which I am currently torturing. In f3, I've got two routes, to root, which echoes a hello world, and to /test, which does this:

```
$f3->route('GET /test', function($f3) { 
    $f3->set('content', 'test.htm');
    echo View::instance()->render('layout.htm');
} );
```

Problem is, when I go to localhost/fatfree-master/test, I get a 404.
But, if I comment out the first route and move the test to root, it works. I was told it's an apache error, but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm sorry if I explained it poorly, did the best I could.

Comment: This may well be your problem, try setting up a virtual Host for FatFree to run in. [How to create a Virtual Host in WampServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `.htaccess` file in your fatfree-master folder? If so, there is a slight bug in the master version for some apache configs. Try to use the `.htaccess` file from the dev-branch at https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/blob/dev/.htaccess and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, joke's on me for not checking the obvious first. I forgot to clear the browser cache. Ctrl+F5 and everything worked. Silly me.